# Trouble with Filling out "hidden" form and clicking "hidden" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, applescript, greasemonkey

On [this site](https://upload.vstanced.com), I'm trying to automate the process of:

1. clicking upload
2. clicking "add image urls"
3. entering the urls
4. hitting submit.

Before that the script gets an image url from an amazon page, and i'm able to do that just fine. Its just the above steps that i'm lost on.

I've experimented with a function I found called "waitforkeyelements", and other similar things i found, to no avail. I cant even seem to click the initial "upload" button, but I noticed that the url doesn't change (at least not during steps 1-3) and the html for the forms and buttons is always there, so i assume its still fillable (just "hidden"). I thought i had it figured out but apparently not. Can anyone offer any insight? here what i got so far: (its meant to start from a page like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1465414177))

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @version     0.1
// @description testing javascript stuff
// @match       http://www.amazon.com/*
// @match       https://www.amazon.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js// 
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
//-- If/when SSL becomes available, switch to only using the https pages.

//$("#artist").val ("username_here");

location.href='http://www.example.com';

  $('body').append('<input type="button" value="Open Image" id="CP">')
  $("#CP").css("position", "fixed").css("bottom", 0).css("right", 0);
  $('#CP').click(function(){ 
      var coverimageurl = $(imgBlkFront).get(0).src;
      //location.href=coverimageurl
      location.href='https://upload.vstanced.com';

      $(".resize-vertical").val (coverimageurl);
      //$("#fullscreen-modal-body").val (coverimageurl);

      $('#btn btn-input default').click()
  });
```

id also be interested in using javascript to "drag and drop" an image on to that page.

also is there an easier way to test what a line or two of javascript does than to repeatedly edit a script, save it, and refresh the @match page?

Edit: heres what im doing now, its applescript and a bit strange, but it works:

```
set filepath to POSIX path of theimage

    tell application "Safari" to open location "https://upload.vstanced.com"
    delay 2
    clickClassName("btn btn-big white outline", 0)
    tell application "System Events"
        activate application "Safari"
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down} --open goto
        set the clipboard to filepath
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        delay 0.7
        keystroke return -- enter goto text
        delay 0.4
        keystroke return --press enter on file

    end tell
```

its a droplet, so it runs and gets "theimage" when i drop a file on it. I guess thats irrelevant though. whats sort of important is ive gotten lots of javascript to play nice with applescript, like the clickclassname thing uses javascript:

```
to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickClassName
```

but i tried to make a function to do your version of step 3 and 4 and it didnt work, i got a little futher using a function for filling forms i found online:

```
to inputByName(theName, num, theValue)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "\n  document.getElementsByName('" & theName & "')[" & num & "].value ='" & theValue & "';" in document 1
    end tell
end inputByName

inputByName("urls", 0, "/Users/Paul/Desktop/image.jpg")
```

i could see that this had filled out the url form, and i made my own function for the whole .submit() part, but that didnt do what it was supposed to. when i run this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.forms[0].submit();" in document 1
end tell
```

i get one of those "are you sure you want to leave the page? the stuff you wrote will be lost" messages. if i click no, nothing happens (i assume because it doesnt do the "submit" thing). if i leave the page i go back to square one. Something funny happens, though, the url becomes what it was with this on the end "/?urls=%2FUsers%2FPaul%2FDesktop%2Fimage.jpg"

i also found a function for clicking, and tried that, but for some reason when i run this:

```
to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickClassName --^credits to cubemg for this

clickClassName("btn btn-input default", 0)
```

It just closes the little urls box. (even though theres stuff in it, and when i hit inspect element on the submit button thats the class name that appears.)

I already tried making an account and doing it, but just for the sake of any future attempts i make, are you logged in when you run it?

I'm going to keep tinkering with it, not sure why im even putting this here in a post with such a javascript centered title. I have made an approach that uses a lot more applescript that does work, but its a bit strange and it uses lots of delays and keystrokes.

Comment: Does anything happen when you click the #CP element? I wonder if it's because the click event isn't getting bound to it since it is created after the page is loaded.

Comment: yeah, the script is supposed to start on an amazon product page, where when you click the CP button the script gets the image url of what you might call an amazon items "main image". Then it loads vstanced.com. It does all of this successfully, but as far as i can tell after doing those steps it doesnt do anything else. Maybe i should make two javascripts? one specifically for vstanced.com? but im not sure how i could pass the imageurl to the other javascript. i guess maybe if theres some way to send and get things from the clipboard then i could do that.

Comment: Hmm, if I remember for security reasons you only have access to the clipboard through flash, not straight js - unless that's changed. Hopefully someone with a better grasp of the issue can chime in, though, as I'm not sure I've got my head properly wrapped around the breaking point.

Comment: To be clear, you want:
  a button on amazon.com, that when clicked, grabs the src of a photo on amazon's page and attempts to upload it to VStanced seamlessly?

Comment: Yes. Currently i'm able to get the src and load vstanced.com just fine. But nothing beyond that. infact, in an ideal world id be able to right click an actual image on my computer and click "get vstanced url" and it would drag and drop it to vstanced. or highlight it and hit a hotkey. but i'm not that optimistic, though i think i could do that with applescript.

Comment: Yea, you're issue is the script is terminated on your location.href change.

Comment: so if i open it in another tab it might work? or is each greasemonkey script confined to the page its on?

Comment: In order to do it like that, you'd need either a separate GM script to run upon opening VStance or to extend the match of this script and add some additional logic. You'd also need to take advantage of GM's get and set value functions to allow for the preservation of your url strings.


http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue

http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue

Answer (score 0):

From the VSstance page, I think this would be easy:

```
//Step 3 - add data to the form
var url = "/path/to/my/photos/photo.jpg";
document.getElementsByName('urls')[0].value = url;
//Step 4 - submit the form
document.forms[0].submit();
```

However, I think if I'm understanding correctly, you're wanting to do this with data you're getting from amazon.com, while on amazon.com. In this case, you're probably going to need to look into ajax/post. I think the location.href modification is going to stop execution of this script and maybe that's where you're getting stuck? This doesn't work, but I'm meaning something similar to:

```
$.post('https://upload.vstanced.com/', { 
    urls: "http://www.amazon.com/picture.jpg"
    });
```

The only other option I see is maybe integrating upload.vstanced.com into amazon.com via iframe.

Comment: i upvoted you but it says it wont take effect till i have a higher reputation. thank you.

Comment: by the way, was your version of steps 3 and 4 working for you? i couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Yes, the form submit works for me - do you have it set to run on VStance in a separate script?

Comment: i tried just the vstanced part with a specific path instead of a variable one, just so i could get an understanding of it. But i was unable, my guess was that it was refusing to accept a url that was a path on my computer, (and that it wanted me to enter that sort of url through the other option.) Do you have a mac? i ended up making an applescript that does it, but i could cut a significant amount of lines off of it if i could just figure that part out. il put just the first couple steps of the applescript that i works right before and during the file choosing window in the description.